# Why is corner radius applied only to top left and right corner for a custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I have my custom view which I use it as a loading bar. It has a bottom layer with opacity 0.1 and a top layer with opacity 1.

Here is how it's setup:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        animation.delegate = self
        bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

        topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        topProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)
        animate(fromValue: 0, toValue: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))

        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height // Update lineWidth
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height    // Update lineWidth

        bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
        topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath

        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    }
```

Now I also want to apply a corner radius, so I added the code at the bottom of `layoutSubviews`:

```
self.clipsToBounds = true
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
```

This only applies the corner radius to the top left and right part, that's it.  And I can't understand why.

I also tried to set it inside `configure` method for `bottomProgressBar` and `topProgressBar` layers, but didn't work at all.

Can someone point what the issue is here ?

edit:

Here is the full class code:

```
class ProgressBar: UIView {

    var bottomProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    var topProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

        topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        topProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)

        animate(toValue: 1)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))

        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height // Update lineWidth
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height    // Update lineWidth

        bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
        topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
    }

    func animate(toValue: Double) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = toValue

        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = CGFloat(toValue)
        topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate")
    }
}
```

edit 2:

Added more screenshots with what is happening:

This is without corner radius applied - simple rectangle

[image]

This is what is happening when I applied corner radius - bottom half is cut out (rectangle is half cut apparently)

[image]

And this is what I want - simple rectangle with corner radius to all 4 corners:

[image]

Comment: You set layers with no frames , do animation in init , it's a messy view

Comment: animation in init is just to have a default value. Still doesn't explain the corner radius issue.

Comment: Post the full class - the code you've shown can't be used as-is, so it's pretty tough to try and help figure out what's not right.

Comment: @DonMag: done. I added the code for the ProgressBar class.

Comment: @Kobe - it looks like you are simply drawing one line overlaid on the other... can you show an image of how you *want* it to look?

Comment: @DonMag: well right now the line is straight, so it is just a rectangle. I want this rectangle to have some corner radius to all 4 side. I will update the question with more screenshots.

Comment: @DonMag: added more screenshots with what is happening and what I want.

Comment: @Kobe - OK... I assume there is a reason you want "top" and "bottom" halves, instead of simply rounding the 4 corners of a rectangle?

Comment: @DonMag: No, I just want corner radius to all 4 corners. Thats it. Not sure what is happening at this point where the bottom half is cut. So just apply corner radius to the first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After clarification of the ultimate goal, here is a simpler way to do it. You can run this directly in a playground page...

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ProgressBar: UIView {

    var progressView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.1)
        layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        clipsToBounds = true

        progressView.frame = bounds
        progressView.frame.size.width = 0.0
        addSubview(progressView)
    }

    func animate(_ pct: CGFloat) -> Void {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.progressView.frame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width * pct
        })
    }

}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var theButton: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        return b
    }()

    var myProgressBar = ProgressBar(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 300, width: 300, height: 30))

    // on button tap, set the progress bar to 80%
    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        myProgressBar.animate(0.8)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        view.addSubview(theButton)
        // constrain button to Top: 32 and centerX
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            theButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        // add an action for the button tap
        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(myProgressBar)

    }

}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Tapping the button will animate the "progress bar" from Zero to 80%

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

First: you are adding a "line" going from `0,0` to `width,0` ... and you're making it's lineWidth the height of your view.

That gives you this result:

[image]

The yellow rectangle is your view, and the white rectangle is your "line". As you see, the **center** of the line is running along the **top** of the view, so the top-half of the line is actually *outside* the view's frame. So when you round the corners of the view, it appears as if only the top corners are being rounded. If you set a background color to your view, you will see that the bottom corners are also being rounded, but you have no "line" there.

If this is what you really want (top bar is white, bottom bar is green):

[image]

you want to set the line-widths to 1/2 of the view height, and set the line-centers at 1/4 and 3/4:

```
class ProgressBar: UIView {

    var bottomProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    var topProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        bottomProgressBar.opacity = 1
        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

        topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
        topProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
        self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)

        //      animate(toValue: 1)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 0.25))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 0.25))

        topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath

        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 0.75))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 0.75))

        bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath

        bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height / 2.0 // Update lineWidth
        topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height / 2.0    // Update lineWidth

        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    }

    func animate(toValue: Double) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        animation.duration = 3.0
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = toValue

        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = CGFloat(toValue)
        topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate")
    }
}
```

Of course, if all you want is a single rectangle with rounded corners, then you don't need either sub-layer... simply create a view with a white background, and set the corner radius of its layer...

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation. Well what I want is yes, just a simple rectangular with rounded corners, but I also need the bottom layer because it's a progress bar, it goes from 0 to 1, so when it has lets say value 0.5, then first half of the view (left side) should be white and the second half should show the bottom layer (with opacity 01.). So just like a progress bar. In my example, the view with all rounded corners has value 1, so bottom layer is hidden.

Comment: Ah... well, you could make it a bit simpler... UIView with background color at opacity 0.1, add subview with opacity 1.0... animate the width of the subview.

Comment: Ok, I think I will try this easy solution

Comment: @Kobe - I edited my answer with a simple example of using a view with a subview... not "finished code" but a decent starting point for you.